# Warning "Consider using varargs for methods or constructors which take an array the last parameter"

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle

I have a method similar to below with the same array type (Java), and I get the below warning from [PMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMD_(software)) when the checks are run.

How do I resolve it?

```
public static double calculateSum(Double[] numArray) {
    ....
}
```

PMD warning:

> Consider using varargs for methods or constructors which take an array
> the last parameter.

Comment: you can do as suggested, use varargs: `pubic static double calculateSum(Double... numArray)` or just ignore the warning (there must also be a way or *option* to turn it off) || despite I do not like the idea of doing that just because some framework/application suggested so; more important is to be sure what the method is expected to receive

Comment: Something seems to be missing in the supposed message from PMD, near *"an array the last parameter"*.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function with a variable number of arguments, add three periods within the parameter declaration:

```
public static double calculateSum(Double... addendum) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (double num : addendum) {
        sum += num;   
    }
    return sum;
}
```